# Find intersection between a line and a circle

Tags: python, vertices, normals, measurement

I'm a beginner in using blender. I have a circular element on top of which is a vertex. I wish to get the location of the intersection of the normal from center of the circle till the vertex with the inner curve region. Is there a way to do this programmatically? Please help. Thank you. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It's a little difficult to know exactly what's going on with your set-up, but I tried to replicate it with a bezierCircle curve with a nurbs path bevel object for 2D thickness and a single vertex from extra mesh objects. I verify the position of intersection by mapping a tiny sphere's location to the intersection. To find the intersection, I found a displacement vector equal to the vert location minus the center of the curve. I used line parameterization to find where a line starting at the center with this displacement vector intersects the inner circle of the curve with a calculated radius.

```
import bpy
from math import sqrt

objs = bpy.context.scene.objects

vert = objs["Vert"]

curve = objs["BezierCircle"]

nurb = objs["NurbsPath"]

v = vert.location

c = curve.location

d = v - c

r = curve.scale.x - nurb.scale.x * 2

t =  r/sqrt(d.x**2 + d.y**2 + d.z**2)

v = c + t*d

sphere = objs["Sphere"]
sphere.location = v
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This definitely gave me a direction to take to solve my problem. :)

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: I have a follow up question on this. I was able to solve the above problem. After that, I was trying to get the 2D location of the a 3D point in the image space. However I observed that whenever I shift to the camera view, the location of the point itself changes. I don't understand why it is happening. Like the point will change its location as soon as I shift to camera view. And my python script seems to be using this camera view location and that's messing up everything for me. Any comments please?